# ISLEAF and IIF MDX to DAX

Tags: mdx, dax, ssas-tabular

I am currently working on migration of SSAS cube from Multidimensional to Tabular. I have many MDX queries. 
For example:
IIF(IsLeaf([Currency].[Currency]),[Measures].[_Discount],null)

I was trying to understand, the above query with some data examples but no luck.

What is the above query mean in MDX?
How could I possibly write this in DAX?

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Currency hierarchy is just one level try:

```
IF(ISFILTERED(‘Currency’[Currency],[_Discount])
```